# Room database query returns null where it should be null-safe in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I have a query that does not have a result, when the DB is empty. Therefore NULL is the correct return value.

However, the compiler in Android Studio gives me the warning: 
Condition 'maxDateTime != null' is always 'true'.

If I debug the code, the null check performs correctly as the value is actually null.

When I rewrite the interface to 'fun queryMaxServerDate(): String?' (notice the question mark), the compiler warning goes away.

But should not 'fun queryMaxServerDate(): String' result in a compilation error since it can be null?

```
@Dao
interface CourseDao {

    // Get latest downloaded entry
    @Query("SELECT MAX(${Constants.COL_SERVER_LAST_MODIFIED}) from course")
    fun queryMaxServerDate(): String

}
```

---

```
// calling function
/**
 * @return Highest server date in table in milliseconds or 1 on empty/error.
 */
fun queryMaxServerDateMS(): Long {
    val maxDateTime = courseDao.queryMaxServerDate()

    var timeMS: Long = 0
    if (maxDateTime != null) { // Warning: Condition 'maxDateTime != null' is always 'true'
        timeMS = TimeTools.parseDateToMillisOrZero_UTC(maxDateTime)
    }
    return if (timeMS <= 0) 1 else timeMS
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying code generated by the annotation is **java** and thus the exception to null safety as per :-

> Kotlin's type system is aimed to eliminate NullPointerException's from
>   our code. The only possible causes of NPE's may be:
>
> An explicit call to throw NullPointerException(); Usage of the !!
>   operator that is described below;
>
> Some data inconsistency with regard
>   to initialization, such as when:
>
> - An uninitialized this available in a
>     constructor is passed and used somewhere ("leaking this");
> - A
>     superclass constructor calls an open member whose implementation in
>     the derived class uses uninitialized state;
> - Java interoperation:
>
>   - Attempts to access a member on a null reference of a platform type;
>   - Generic types used for Java interoperation with incorrect nullability,
>       e.g. a piece of Java code might add null into a Kotlin
>       MutableList, meaning that MutableList should be used
>       for working with it;
>   - Other issues caused by external Java code.

[Null Safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)

e.g. the generated code for **queryMaxServerDate()** in **CourseDao** would be along the lines of :-

```
  @Override
  public String queryMaxServerDate() {
    final String _sql = "SELECT max(last_mopdified) from course";
    final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 0);
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    final Cursor _cursor = DBUtil.query(__db, _statement, false, null);
    try {
      final String _result;
      if(_cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        final String _tmp;
        _tmp = _cursor.getString(0);
        _result = _tmp;
      } else {
        _result = null;
      }
      return _result;
    } finally {
      _cursor.close();
      _statement.release();
    }
  }
```

As you can see, no data extracted (no first row) and null is returned.